# How to refresh UserControl or Call User control function from Parent serverside in ASP.Net C#?

Tags: asp.net, download, user-controls, postback, registerstartupscript

I have a page with button for download a file, after I press that , I want a user control to be refreshed .that can be done with a function I wrote in UC.

So: 
How Can I **Call a js Function in User_Control from Parent server-side**(after user press **Download**_button to download a file)

I used this code, but it doesn't work?

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"UpdateReportList", "UpdateReportList();", true);
```

> Note: UpdateReportList() is js function in my user control .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(sFilePath)` writes the attachment to the entire response body and no other markup or script get appended through  `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()`. That's the reason you don't see of triggering `UpdateReportList()` in the browser.

The approach to be changed, there are couple of other options to achieve this functionality.

1. Set a cookie instead of `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` as it's part of response header. Start a javascript timer using `setInterval()`, request to download, read the cookie, stop the timer, clear the cookie and call `UpdateReportList()`.
2. Move the entire code to asp.net generic handler (.ashx) and repeat the same steps as described above.
3. You can think of some other options based on your requirement.

Comment: It depends on, a file download time is unknown. So a timer can be an option, a post is available. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download.

Answer (score 1):

based on @Sudipta Maiti for my question , and @puddleglum answer in this link [Update page after file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025288/update-page-after-file-download)  I changed my code as this :

on Download button OnClientClick event , I add this lines before returning to server:

```
setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 3000);
```

so I will have a short delay,and then reloading the page.